# Help with partition/width

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

Let $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    1,& \text{if } x=\frac{2}{n} \text{ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$};\\ 
    0,              & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

We need to prove the function is Riemann integrable on $[0,2].$

I think I can do the epsilon proof on this. I have $M_i$ = $\frac{2}{n-1}$

I am having trouble deciding on the correct $\Delta x_{i}$ because the widths are changing. Aren't they a function of $i$?

Comment: Is it necessary that $x=2/n$ in least form for $f(x) = 1$? For example, is $f(1) = 0$ or $1$?

Comment: Perhaps, I should have made this more clear. Let $E = \left\{\frac{2}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$. Thus, $f(x) = 1$ if $ x\in E$.

Comment: You can see that $f$ is bounded and is discontinuous at points $x=2/n,n=1,2,\cdots$. The set of discontinuities clearly has a single limit point $0$ and thus $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,2]$. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2538438/72031).

Answer (score 1):

I can show that the upper sum minus the lower sum can be made arbitrarily small by choosing the partitions carefully. In this case, **yes**, the lengths of the subintervals will vary (at least, they vary in my construction).

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Without loss of generality assume $\varepsilon < 1$.  For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we will select an interval $I_n$ around the point $\frac{2}{n} \in [0,2]$ having length
$$
l(I_n) = \frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}.
$$
Such an interval can be fixed as
$$
I_{n} = \biggl[ \frac{2}{n\vphantom{2^{n+1}}} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}}, \frac{2}{n\vphantom{2^{n+1}}} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{n+1}} \biggr] = [a_n,b_n].
$$
Note that $\frac{2}{n} \in I_n$ and if $m \neq n$ then $\frac{2}{n} \not\in I_m$. Let $P_N$ be the partition of $[0,2]$ containing the points $\{ 0,a_N,b_N,a_{N-1},b_{N-1},\dots,a_1,b_1,1 \}$. Then, the lower sum $L(f,P_N)$ will be $0$ because every subinterval will contain points not of the form $\frac{2}{n}$. Let
$$
M_n = \max\{ f(x) : x \in [a_n,b_n] \}, \qquad 1 \leq n \leq N,
$$
and
$$
K_n = \max\{ f(x) : x \in [b_n, a_{n-1}] \}, \qquad 1 < n \leq N.
$$
Clearly, $M_n = 1$ for each $1 \leq n \leq N$ and $K_n = 0$ for each $1 < n \leq N$. Also, define
$$
M_{N+1} = \max\{ f(x) : x \in [0,a_N]\}
$$
and
$$
K_1 = \max\{ f(x) : x \in [b_1,1] \}.
$$
Clearly, $M_{N+1} = 1$ and $K_1 = 0$. So, the upper sum $U(f,P_N)$ can be written as
$$
\begin{align*}
U(f,P) &= \sum_{n=1}^{N} M_{n} \cdot l(I_n) + M_{N+1} \cdot l([0,a_N]) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{\varepsilon}{2^n} + \biggl(\frac{2}{N\vphantom{2^N+1}} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{N+1}} \biggr) \\
&= \varepsilon\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^N} \right) + \biggl(\frac{2}{N\vphantom{2^N+1}} - \frac{\varepsilon}{2^{N+1}} \biggr) \\
&= \varepsilon\left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^{N+1}} \right) + \frac{2}{N} \\
&< \varepsilon + \frac{2}{N}
\end{align*}
$$
since $1 - \frac{1}{2^{N+1}} < 1$. So, by choosing $N$ sufficiently large so that $\frac{2}{N} < \varepsilon$, we get
$$
U(f,P_N) - L(f,P_N) = U(f,P_N) < 2\varepsilon.
$$
Hence, $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

For each interval in your partition, the infimum is $0$, while the supremum is either $0$ if no $2/n$ is in the interval or $1$ if some $2/n$ is in the interval. Thus the lower sum is $0$ while the upper sum is the sum of the lengths of all intervals which contain some $2/n$. Thus you need to choose partitions such that the total length of those intervals which contain some $2/n$ is arbitrarily small. Hint: you can cram all but finitely many $2/n$'s into *one* interval.

If you haven't proven the equivalence between Riemann and Darboux integration, the situation is very similar when using the definition of Riemann integration directly, without reference to lower/upper sums.